# java directory permissions with AccessController.checkPermission

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

im trying to get directory permissions via the checkPermission() method, as in the code.

```
private static boolean dirPermissions(String dir, String perm) {
    try {
        AccessController.checkPermission(new FilePermission(dir, perm));
        return true;
    } catch (AccessControlException e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

the java (<=6) documentation for most of the relevant File class methods (e.g. canRead(), canWrite(), etc.) suggest that they are useful for file, but not directories (am i wrong here?).

im not running the code on a server, or running mutliple threads and need to save acc's between them, or doing anything tricky, its as simple as can be - a fresh eclipse install with local running jvm and code, and im accessing local directories.

however, checkPermission always throws an exception (i.e. access denied) for folders that obviously the jvm has read/write permissions to because i can manage to create folders and write to files etc.

presumably it isn't related to the local java.policy because im successfully writing to files, so i have the necessary security permissions. any ideas...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly you should probably be using the `SecurityManager`.

`FilePermission` copes with directories fine. You probably want to include all the files and directories included below. Use `/-` at the end for that. Use `/*` for non-recursive contained files and directories.

`checkPermission` will throw an exception if any frame (or rather its `ProtectionDomain`) of the current access control context (acc) does not have the required permission.

`FilePermission` has nothing to do with OS permissions.

Comment: Hawtin, well then presumably ive been barking up the wrong tree. if not like this, how should i be retrieving OS directory permissions, such as would be the output of the command ls -l ?

Comment: I believe "More NIO Features" in JDK7 supports it. That or a similar library for 1.6, or just old school parsing the output of `ls -l`.