# Access check on folder in java

Tags: java, permissions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [java directory permissions with AccessController.checkPermission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4483303/java-directory-permissions-with-accesscontroller-checkpermission)

I'm using the following code to check the access on selected folder. But it's not working.

```
private boolean writeAccess(String path){
    try {
        AccessController.checkPermission(new FilePermission(path, "read,write"));/*,*/
        // Has permission
        return true;

        } 
    catch (SecurityException e) {
        // Does not have permission
        return false;
    }   
}
```

What is problem in it. And is there any other options to check the existance and access on the folders/directories?

Comment: what does "not working" mean? throws exception?

Comment: its returning true for all the unaccessable folders.

Comment: dirPermissions("C:\Documents and Settings\bkh4kor\Desktop","WRITE")
it's always giving false i.e no access.

Answer (score 0):

No, your code checks whether the code itself has permissions with respect to the Java Security Policy in effect. In all probability you don't even have Java Security active. What you are looking for are the methods in the `File` class, check it out: [`canRead`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#canRead%28%29), `canWrite`, etc.